# helm logic display the value

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

thi is my current configuration, I cannot get it work with the logic, attempted multiple time with different location placing for the quote, any idea?

deployment.yaml

```
<indent 10>- name: CONF
<indent 10>- value: ssl://{{ .Values.CONF_NAME }}.{{ .Values.namespace }}
```

values.yaml

```
CONF_NAME: a2727e740e1102d2
namespace: app
```

I want to add a logic to check true and false in order to add this env

deployment.yaml

```
{{- if .Values.confname1.update }}
{{ "- name: CONF" | nindent 10 }}
{{ "- value: ssl://{{ .Values.CONF_NAME }}.{{ .Values.namespace }}" | nindent 10 }}
{{- end }}
```

values.yaml

```
confname1:
  update: true
CONF_NAME: a2727e740e1102d2baddd47199efcef2?
namespace: app
```

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[16]): missing required field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvVar
```

Comment: In both versions of the `deployment.yaml` file, the hyphen before `value:` separates the environment variable name from its value.  This needs to be turned into a space.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't add quotes and brackets around the block inside the if statement, also the - before the if is wrong, try something like this:

```
{{ if .Values.confname1.update }}
 - name: CONF
   value: ssl://{{ .Values.CONF_NAME }}.{{ .Values.namespace }}
{{ end }}
```

[EDIT] Here is a an example that's properly indented.

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api-name
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
        env:
        {{ if .Values.confname1.update }}
        - name: CONF
          value: ssl://{{ .Values.CONF_NAME }}.{{ .Values.namespace }}
        {{ end }}
```

Comment: thank you and I follow your suggestion still getting error

'''
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[16]): missing required field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvVar
'''

Comment: are you working with env variables? so something like: env: - name: .. value ..? most likely this is indentation related

Comment: Yes, define after

```
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
        env:
```

Comment: @Francis I added an example that's properly formatted in my answer as I couldn't format that in the comments, can you make sure your yaml file is correctly indented?